# Using serilog with azure application insights and .Net core

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, serilog

Currently, I am using azure application insights directly for logging as given in this link
[Use latest version of Application Insight with .net core API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772015/use-latest-version-of-application-insight-with-net-core-api)
and everything is working fine.

But I need to use the serilog for logging now with the help of azure application insight. Even I do some R&D about serilog (https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights). But didn't get any idea. Could you please suggest me that how can we achieve that with the .Net core 3.0

Comment: What is the problem? You've linked to the Serilog application insights sink which is exactly what you need to add to your project. I speak from experience when I say it works

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 How can I linked?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please follow the steps below:

**First, in stall the following packages:**

[Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore, version 2.14.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/2.14.0)

[Serilog.AspNetCore, version 3.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.AspNetCore/3.2.0)

[Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights, version 3.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights/)

[Serilog.Settings.Configuration, version 3.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Settings.Configuration/)

**In Program.cs:**

```
public class Program
{     
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
           .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration{ ConnectionString = "xxxxxxxxx" },TelemetryConverter.Traces)
             );                
}
```

**In controller.cs**:

[image]

**The test result**:

[image]

Comment: How do you configure application insights settings like sampling configuration?

Comment: Where the instrumentation key comes from?

Comment: @LesairValmont, if you have an Application Insights created, then please go to azure portal -> your Application Insights -> Overview page: then you can find Instrumentation Key there.

Comment: Mine is actually working but... any ideas on why isn't the "live telemetry" actually working?

Comment: I think you forgot to add how appsettings.json looks for serilog

Answer (score -2):

Here is information how to setup app configuration for asp net core, but it for v6.x

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6

appsettings.json (example)

```
{
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "Copy connection string from Application Insights Resource Overview"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not answer the part regarding Serilog in the question

Comment: The solution does not mention serilog.