# how to configure serilog and applicationinsights in App.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-application-insights, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I was trying to do this to configure serilog to write to application insights. it is in app.config file. But it doesn't work. Is there any alternative approach

```
<add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Error"/>
<add key="serilog:using:ApplicationInsights" value="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:ApplicationInsights" value="fxxx104-dd93-xxxx-8601-xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

Comment: Your question is missing some detail. You haven't shown the code where you initialize the logger. Please provide a [mcve]. Also [check the documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog) for how to enable the self-log capability and update your question with the findings.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `UseSerilog` in Program.cs. You use App.config just want the read keys by code, something like `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]`.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
       .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
           .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
           .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration{ InstrumentationKey = "xxxxxxxxx" },TelemetryConverter.Traces)
        );
```

Then you can use `Log.Information("log details")` in yourController.cs to record logs.

**Thanks for Ivan's soultion. For more details, you can refer his answer in below post.**

[Using serilog with azure application insights and .Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61907115/using-serilog-with-azure-application-insights-and-net-core)